# NullPointerException on a Button Click event

Tags: android

GridActivity.java

```
        // Get feed form the file
        feed = (RSSFeed) getIntent().getExtras().get("feed");

        createFeedGroup();
```

It's a newbie question. I have three ImageButtons on a FragmentActivity. When I click on btn_2 and btn_3, it listens to the event but if I click on the btn_1, it gives me an error.

```
btn_1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {

        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GridActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);

      }
});

btn_2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {

        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SplashActivity.class);                   startActivity(i);

       }
});

btn_3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {

        openContextMenu(v);
    }   

});
```

Here's the stacktrace:

```
04-24 08:29:10.022: E/AndroidRuntime(5176): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.td.rssreader/com.td.rssreader.GridActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-24 08:29:10.022: E/AndroidRuntime(5176):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2088)
04-24 08:29:10.022: E/AndroidRuntime(5176):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2113)
04-24 08:29:10.022: E/AndroidRuntime(5176):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:139)
04-24 08:29:10.022: E/AndroidRuntime(5176):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1224)
04-24 08:29:10.022: E/AndroidRuntime(5176):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-24 08:29:10.022: E/AndroidRuntime(5176):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-24 08:29:10.022: E/AndroidRuntime(5176):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4918)
04-24 08:29:10.022: E/AndroidRuntime(5176):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-24 08:29:10.022: E/AndroidRuntime(5176):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-24 08:29:10.022: E/AndroidRuntime(5176):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
04-24 08:29:10.022: E/AndroidRuntime(5176):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
04-24 08:29:10.022: E/AndroidRuntime(5176):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-24 08:29:10.022: E/AndroidRuntime(5176): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-24 08:29:10.022: E/AndroidRuntime(5176):     at com.td.rssreader.GridActivity.onCreate(GridActivity.java:54)
04-24 08:29:10.022: E/AndroidRuntime(5176):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5048)
04-24 08:29:10.022: E/AndroidRuntime(5176):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
04-24 08:29:10.022: E/AndroidRuntime(5176):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2052)
04-24 08:29:10.022: E/AndroidRuntime(5176):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Can you please show the code of your `GridActivity` the error occurs in the onCreate of that class?

Comment: use getActivity() instead of getApplicationContext()

Comment: The relevant line of your Stacktrace is: `com.td.rssreader.GridActivity.onCreate(GridActivity.java:54)`. This is where you try to access a null object.

Comment: Looks like there is something wrong in your GridActivity, can you post the code of GridActivity too?

Comment: Looks like your problem is from your GridActivity, not from your listener, can you pst the code of this one ?

Comment: Please post the code of your `GridActivity.java` file `onCreate()` method.

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at com.td.rssreader.GridActivity.onCreate(GridActivity.java:54)` means post the code around this line.

Comment: your error is here: GridActivity.onCreate(GridActivity.java:54) use  Intent i = new Intent(myactivityName.this, GridActivity.class);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to retrieve the feed from the Intent without putting it into your starting Intent:

From `GridActivity`:

```
feed = (RSSFeed) getIntent().getExtras().get("feed");
```

You'll need to start it like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GridActivity.class);
i.putExtra("feed", feed);
startActivity(i);
```

Note that RSSFeed might have to implement [`Parcelable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) for this to work.